# Sentencias UPDATE preparadas mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

siempre e tenido problemas al descontar unidades de una producto

**Contexto:**
Yo al generar un pedido lo genero asi (ejemplo resumido)

`1:3;2:4;3:10;` (id_producto:cantidad;id_producto:cantidad;id_producto:cantidad;)

Ahora bien esto lo meto en una variable y luego lo separo con un explode y luego recorro el bucle y en cada vuelta descuento las unidades:

```
foreach($var as $var2){
// $var2 es un array generado por explode(":",...); donde tengo [0]id_producto;[1]cantidad a vender
$bdcon->query("update productos set unidades = unidades - ".$var2["1"]." where id_producto = $var2["0"]);
}
```

Con esto descuento unidades actuales - unidades a vender; el codigo funciona bien lo e probado varias veces; sin embargo siempre encuentro 1 u otra ocacion en la que no se desconto bien a pesar de que el codigo funciona bien y mis ventas tambien envia bien la data.
E investigado sobre procesos almacenados mysql pero la verdad es que no encuentro para `update` y/o que se acople a lo que yo estoy haciendo.

**Mi pregunta es:**
Existe alguna forma mas eficiente en la cual pueda descontar los stock y alguien tiene algun ejemplo de procedimientos almacenados para poder implementar a mi sistema?

Muchas gracias por su tiempo amigos espero sus comentarios

Comment: Podrías crear una tabla de `recibos` (_seguro se te ocurre un nombre mejor_) donde guardas para cada producto la cantidad recibida y por otro lado `enviado` (_idem_) donde guardas cuantos de cada producto se enviaron. ¿Necesitas saber el stock actual? Suma lo recibido y resta lo enviado

Comment: La mejor forma de resolver esto es con un `TRIGGER`, el cual se disparará de forma automática cada vez que haya una modificación en la tabla dependiente de ese TRIGGER, actualizando los valores en la tabla que controlará la existencia.

Answer (score 0):

Pues seria hacer lo mismo pero con un trigger y lo solucionarías, esto hará que cada vez que cambie el valor de la tabla esta se actualice y incluso podrás hacer copias de lo que tenias antes

```
USE DB; 
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS prueba $$
CREATE TRIGGER prueba AFTER UPDATE ON tuTabla
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
       update productos set unidades = unidades - tuValor where id_producto = TuCondicon;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

## Trigger o Disparadores.

Se trata de una rutina almacenada que se ejecuta de forma automática cuando se produce un evento

- INSERT, DELETE o UPDATE

Los Triggers se asocian a tablas (los procedimientos y funciones se asociaban a un BD).

## Las instrucciones asociadas a los disparadores son :

```
CREATE TRIGGER….
SHOW TRIGGER….
DROP TRIGGER… #Para modificar un Trigger que se borre y se reescribe
```

## ¿Cuando se dispara un trigger - Momento del disparo?

**BEFORE, AFTER (de la operación a realizar: INSERT, DELETE o UPDATE)
Esto nos da 6 posibilidades :** BEFORE INSERT, AFTER INSERT, BEFORE DELETE, AFTER DELETE, BEFORE UPDATE, AFTER UPDATE

## En una tabla no puede haber dos disparadores del mismo tipo (Ejemplo BEFORE DELETE)

**-FOR EACH ROW BEGIN….. END** Indica las instrucciones que hay que realizar con cada fila de datos

## Utilización de alias OLD y NEW

**Existen combinaciones que no tienen sentido :** INSERT con OLD y DELETE con NEW

**Nota :** Debes de adaptar esta información a tu código

Comment: pero en concreto aplicado a php ? porque yo programo en php mysql amigow